# Yocto configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 >= 3.14.0) were not met

Tags: gtk3, autotools, yocto

I'm trying to build an application in Yocto which complains about a package not being found, which is in fact there. GTK+3 is installed on my the yocto build. Yet the packageconfig complains about GTK+3. What should I do?

Yocto configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 >= 3.14.0) were not met. Full error is as follows:

```
| checking for gtk+-3.0 >= 3.14.0... no
| configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 >= 3.14.0) were not met:
| 
| No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
| 
| Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
| installed software in a non-standard prefix.
| 
| Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GTK_CFLAGS
| and GTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
| See the pkg-config man page for more details.
| NOTE: The following config.log files may provide further information.
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered on many occasions for various Linux distributions. However, I could not find any contribution regarding Yocto-based Linux builds. I decided to do it Q&A style.

This problem happened to me when installing `plymouth` package with `PACKAGECONFIG_append = "gtk"`. But I assume the solution would help with many other packages.

The problem is due to not having a dependent package information provided. You should create a .bbappend to the package and add (in my case):

```
DEPENDS_append = " gtk+3"
```

This solution worked for me perfectly.

Comment: Instead of writing a bbappend, please fix the plymouth recipe.